# ui-sref-active for nested status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built the menu link using angular-js and ui-route.

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="dashboard" title="Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Dashboard</span></a>
</li>
```

It worked successfully, but if i entered sub state for example dashboard.view, then the link doesn't be changed to active.

You can check via below url.

In http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts, the contact tab is actived, but 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1, the contact tab is not actived.

so How can i build the html link for active of nested status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is not implemented in the currently released code. Currently, the `ui-sref-active` directive checks the status of the exact UI state set by the `ui-sref` attribute it is attached to. It does not check whether the state it is responding to has active sub states. A change is currently being implemented to allow functionality for sub-state like you have described. See [AngularUI Router Issue #819](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/819)

Comment: As a side note, today I discovered the [includedByState](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.filter:includedByState) filter. The code would be a little more ugly, but you might be able to use that or [$state.includes](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) to conditionally apply your class in the markup.